# Open a new page on click of a link on new window

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a page in which i have provided a link clicking on which should redirect to a new page on the new window.

My code is

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="webMnu" onclick="window.open('http://abc.com','plain');">Enroll</a>
```

The problem is that it is working fine in firefox(opens in a new tab) but in internet explorer its opening in a popup (not in a new tab).

How can i open this new page in new tab?

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Pankaj

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible; it is a user preference in the browser whether to make a new window or a new tab, and if the user doesn't set the preference in Internet Explorer, it opens a new window.

Comment: window.open will always attempt to open a popup window, target=_blank will attempt to open a 'normal' window/tab. of course if the user has configured these differently then they'll act differently :)

Comment: Correct - You cannot force a link to open in a new tab in IE. It's down to user preferences.

Comment: sorry my (slight) bad, it seems ie8's default behaviour is different, see my comment on my answer below :P

Comment: User preferences my ass. If it's down to user preferences, they why are we allowed to tell the browser to open a new window!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want

```
<a href="http://abc.com" target="_blank">Enroll</a>
```

window.open is for popup windows, if you just want a new browser window/tab, target=_blank is your friend.

Comment: That's not a JavaScript solution though.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying but the problem remains in internet explorer its still opening in a new popup

Comment: @kinopiko why does it need to be? the requirement was 'I have a page in which i have provided a link clicking on which should redirect to a new page on the new window.'

Comment: @pankaj, which version of ie? that code should open in a new window (which means tab for modern browsers, unless you've configured it differently?)

Comment: have a look under Tools > Internet Options > General > Tabs [Settings] > "Always open pop-ups in a new window" (selected by default), "Always open pop-ups in a new tab", or "Let Internet Explorer decide how pop-ups should open" which is the one you want.

Comment: But, relying on the end-user's browser settings is not a good idea, unless you are developing an application for internal use, and you are able to ensure that all users have their browsers configured in the same way. Unpredictable behaviour is a sure-fire way to alienate users.