# open a new window on click of sub menu item

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Requirement is when i click on one of the page tab, jsp page should open in a new window.
Below is the JS code to create tab:

menu.js

```
        var mySubMenu = new DropDownMenu({});
         mySubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
             label: "Show Data",
             onClick:function(){"<a href=\"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/showData.jsp target=_blank>";}

         }));
         mySubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
             label: "Display Log",
             onClick:function(){window.location.href=contextPath+"/jsp/displayLog.jsp"}

         }));

         pMenuBar.addChild(new PopupMenuBarItem({
             label: "| Help",
             popup: mySubMenu
         }));
```

showData.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/myApplication/js/menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body><form>
Some Text Here</form></body>
```

Please correct me where i'm doing wrong , as when i click on Show Data tab no behavior is seen on the web page. I want to open showData.jsp in new window when i click on Show Data tab. I don't want to open in same page, a new window should open on click of tab. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a new page on click of a link on new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620765/open-a-new-page-on-click-of-a-link-on-new-window)

Comment: Could you please ass the HTML (JSP) part? And describe howe those JS prototype functions are called?

Comment: @tmarwen - please see the post above, included the code.

Comment: And where does the `DropDownMenu` object is declared, are using any third-party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a string when you click 'showData' (no effect). Instead you need to execute JS just like you do for Display Log:

```
     mySubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
         label: "Show Data",
         onClick:function(){
             //"<a href=\"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/showData.jsp target=_blank>";
             window.open("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/showData.jsp");
         }

     }));
```

You can configure the window you are trying to open based on the
[window.open docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open).